# including react jsx dependencies, npm install fails

Tags: reactjs, electron, npm-install

The information I have surrounding the issue is perhaps tangential

but I've create an electron app that uses react, but *without* using `create-react-app`

no going back, so now i'm trying to include dev dependencies for working with jsx

my dependencies look like this

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "electron": ">=11.2.3",
        "electron-reload": ">=1.5.0",
        "graphql": "^14.5.8",
        "react": ">=17.0.1",
        "react-dom": ">=17.0.1",
        "react-scripts": ">=4.0.1",
        "concurrently": ">=7.2.2",
        "wait-on": ">=6.0.1"
    }
```

and i'm getting these errors

```
199 silly placeDep ROOT react-refresh@0.11.0 OK for: @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.7 want: >=0.10.0 <1.0.0
200 silly placeDep ROOT webpack@5.73.0 OK for: @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.7 want: >=4.43.0 <6.0.0
201 timing idealTree Completed in 2680ms
202 timing command:install Completed in 2683ms
203 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined
203 verbose stack     at Arborist.[canPlaceDep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1284:15)
203 verbose stack     at Arborist.[placeDep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1061:36)
203 verbose stack     at Arborist.[placeDep] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1212:41)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

I've included the current versions for the last three packages, `react-scripts`, `concurrently` and `wait-on`, which is where i'm running into issues.

Edit:
For anyone who finds this, I had an unsupported version of node, and on windows 11, npm couldn't update it, so I had to get nvm to update node, from here:

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.9/nvm-setup.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known [bug](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1257) in v6.

Upgrade your `npm` to above version 6 (`npm install -g npm`) to fix it.

Comment: thanks for the heads up

got some warnings, looking to update node as well

I'll get back with the result :-)